# Ionic 4 Node Module Errors when converting JavaScript Date to FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am simply trying to convert a JavaScript date to a FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp as such:

```
import { Timestamp } from "@google-cloud/firestore";

... 

myTimeConversionFunction() {
  let myDOBTimestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
}
```

I then get the following litany of errors when I add the above code to my page:

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/operationsClient.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-gax/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/util.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/aws-sign2'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/aws4'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/ecc-jsbn'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node/crypto.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/http-signature/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/verify.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/http-signature/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/jwa'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/oauth-sign/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/oauth-sign'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/hawk.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/certificate.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/private-key.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/signature.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/utils.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/fingerprint.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/dhe.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/key.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/identity.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/pem.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/ssh-private.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats/openssh-cert.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-dns.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/tls-helpers.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/util.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/gtoken/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/http_proxy.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/forever-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/http-signature/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/subchannel.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http2' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/forever-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/subchannel-address.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/subchannel.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-ip.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolver-dns.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channelz.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/forever-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/service-config.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_admin_client.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1beta1/firestore_client.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1beta1'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/util.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/operationsClient.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-gax/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/mime-types'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/assert-plus'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/combined-stream/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/paginationCalls/pageDescriptor.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/paginationCalls'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/isstream/isstream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/isstream'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/jws/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/jws/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/jws/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/retry-request'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/sshpk/lib/ed-compat.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/sshpk/lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/http_proxy.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel-credentials.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/subchannel.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/forever-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/tunnel-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/compression-filter.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/request.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/wpghijsen/Programs/instancefour/treetopthree/node_modules/request'

I am simply trying to convert the date and store it as a FirestoreTimestamp, given the errors, am I doing this correctly?

Comment: check if your `node_modules` folder exists.

Comment: @WillemGhjson any update?

Comment: I ended up using firebase.firestore.timestamp from the firebase library and everything worked out